# Simulating touch event on YUI 3

Tags: javascript, touch, yui, yui3

I want to simulate / fire a touch event (touchstart or touchend) on a link with YUI 3.

The function .simulate doesn't handle the 'touch event', but only click/dblclick etc....

When i search in the official doc, there is nothing about it on the event section.

Is there anyway to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: YUI doesn't have support for simulating touch events. You could file a ticket for it http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui3/newticket/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use touchstart or touch{move,end} on non-touch device.
Maybe you want to try to fire a 'gesturemovestart', that should be cross-device.
 Y.one.('#yourLink').fire('gesturemovestart')
See http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/touch.html#move

When the link is clicked, I fire  'gesturemovestart': http://jsfiddle.net/DrMw8/

Best regards,
Ludo

Comment: My dev is for iPad/iPhone so the device is a touch-one. It's just that i use webViews.

Comment: Does none of those work? Y.one.('#yourLink').fire('gesturemovestart'); or Y.one.('#yourLink').fire('touchstart');

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for simulation of touch events yet. It's documented here: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/simulate.html#no-touch-events-yet